# How to read transaction history from realm file?

Tags: realm

I have a realm database, where my user deleted all data and commited that transaction. I think I've seen a tool inside realm-core, that able to show all data stored inside a realm file on transaction level. Using sources of that tool I'm going to revert last transaction.

- Do I remember correctly about that tool?
- Could you suggest me an another example or API name that able to read contents of realm file on transaction level?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. When data is deleted from a Realm file, it's really deleted, it's not soft delete or something along those lines. When deleting data, the Realm file stays the same size, but that's so it can efficiently re-use the space for future objects. If this was a synced Realm, there's a possibility of restoring the Server Based data from a backup - you would have to work with Realm directly on that.

Answer (score 0):

If - and only if - the commit you mentioned is the very last commit done to the file, it should be possible to recover it by flipping bit 0 in byte 23 of the file and reopening it. This is because changes made in a transaction is always made without immediately overwriting current data. But if yet another transaction has been committed, the original data will be at least partially overwritten.

Comment: Is this answer based on any documentation you can link (e.g. how in the world would you know that?)